# Send file, with images which are stored internally, to external recipients

Tags: vba, image, excel

I send a file with images to clients.  When the client opens the file all the images are gone or there is an error message.  This document is updated weekly with new inventory data.

All images reference column E and images are saved to a folder within the company server.

The code I have been using is:

```
Sub IMAGEINSERT()

Dim pictureNameColumn As String 'column where picture name is found
Dim picturePasteColumn As String 'column where picture is to be pasted

Dim pictureName As String 'picture name
Dim lastPictureRow As Long 'last row in use where picture names are
Dim pictureRow As Long 'current picture row to be processed
Dim pathForPicture As String 'path of pictures

pictureNameColumn = "E"
picturePasteColumn = "A"

pictureRow = 2 'starts from this row

'error handler
On Error GoTo Err_Handler

'find row of the last cell in use in the column where picture names are
lastPictureRow = Cells(Rows.Count, pictureNameColumn).End(xlUp).Row

'stop screen updates while macro is running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

pathForPicture = "M:\Sales\Accessories\Hope G\_OFF PRICE\_ATS REPORTS\ATS LIST\images\"

'loop till last row
Do While (pictureRow <= lastPictureRow)

    pictureName = Cells(pictureRow, "E") 'This is the picture name

    'if picture name is not blank then
    If (pictureName <> vbNullString) Then

        'check if pic is present
        If (Dir(pathForPicture & pictureName & ".jpg") <> vbNullString) Then

            'This is where picture will be inserted
            Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Select

            'Path to where pictures are stored
            ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pathForPicture & pictureName & ".jpg").Select

            With Selection
                .Left = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Left
                .Top = Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn).Top
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .ShapeRange.Height = 80#
                .ShapeRange.Width = 60#
                .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
            End With
        Else
            'picture name was there, but no such picture
           Cells(pictureRow, picturePasteColumn) = ""
        End If
    Else
        'picture name cell was blank
    End If

    'increment row count
    pictureRow = pictureRow + 1
Loop

Exit_Sub:
Range("A10").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox "Error encountered. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
GoTo Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What error message? Is it about macro enabling? Could you keep the .XLSM for yourself and send a dated copy in .XLSX format to those clients ?

Comment: It is possible that the same server location is mapped under a different letter for the user. I don't know what event fires your Macro, but if it does, it may not find the location.  
A trivial check, but I would start with that.

Comment: I don't see any issues in posted code. You can see those images from the attachment in Sent items? Does the client see a shape placeholder at all? if you can remove business confidential contents and then share the file, it may be easier to find the cause. It should not be unable to access your server share as it's a copy of the image being inserted, not a link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the clients you're sending the file to are external clients.

The Pictures.Insert method only creates a link to the picture, so external clients which don't have access to your company server won't be able to see the pictures.

You need to instead use the Shapes.AddPicture method, which can embed the picture in the file.

```
Activesheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=pathForPicture & pictureName & ".jpg", _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=Selection.Left, Top:=Selection.Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1
```

Note that the Width and Height parameters are mandatory, but you can set them to -1, which then maintains the height and width of the original image!